# How to add a click event on dynamically created imagebox?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I created around 12 picbox and label dynamically im able to retrieve data in the picbox and label from SQL. the picbox image in binary format and the row where imagestore in table also contain image title's in database.

The problem is that I want to add a click_event on picbox. ASAP I click on picbox a textbox1. text which I created must show the title of the image which is store in the SQL.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace library
{
    public partial class showingmore : Form
    {
        private string passvalue;
        public string passval
        {
            get { return passvalue; }
            set { passvalue = value; }
        }
        public showingmore()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        MemoryStream ms;
        byte[] photo_aray;


        private void showingmore_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=sa;Password =12345678; Initial Catalog=library; server=raj; TRUSTED_CONNECTION=true;");
            OleDbDataAdapter Adap = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from movie ", con);
            textBox1.Text = passvalue;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            Adap.Fill(ds);

            //textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[15][0].ToString(); // the working way to use ds to fill data

            //textBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[1];
            //int icount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            //textBox1.Text = icount.ToString();

           /**** Creating Label's and Picture Box ****/ 
            int n = 12; // total time for running loop.
            int j = 14; // y-axis co-ordinate label 
            int k = 479; // x-axis co-ordinate label
            int l = 18; // y-axis co-ordinate label

            // Creating label through loop's.
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                //Create label
                Label labels = new Label();
                PictureBox picbox = new PictureBox();
                labels.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();

                if (i <= 5)
                {
                    //Position label on screen
                    labels.Location = new Point(j, k);
                    j = j + 228;
                    // Label text color
                    labels.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                }
                else
                {
                    k = 782; // x-axis co-ordinate
                    labels.Location = new Point(l, k);
                    l = l + 228;
                    labels.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                }
                this.Controls.Add(labels);
            }

            n = 12; // total time for running loop.
            j = 18; // y-axis co-ordinate 
            k = 246; // x-axis co-ordinate
            l = 18; // y-axis co-ordinate

            // Creating PictureBox through loop's.
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                //Create PictureBox
                PictureBox picbox = new PictureBox();
                picbox.Image = null;
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][14] != System.DBNull.Value)
                {
                    photo_aray = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][14];
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo_aray);
                    picbox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                }

                if (i <= 5)
                {
                    //Position PictureBox on screen
                    picbox.Location = new Point(j, k);
                    picbox.Size = new Size(161, 220);
                    picbox.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                    j = j + 228;
                }
                else
                {
                    k = 543; // y-axis co-ordinate
                    picbox.Location = new Point(l, k);
                    picbox.Size = new Size(161, 220);
                    picbox.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                    l = l + 228;
                }

                this.Controls.Add(picbox);


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this somewhere in the loop before adding the picbox to the `Controls` collection:

```
picbox.MouseClick += picbox_MouseClick;
```

Then, implement the handler for the click somewhere in your `showingmore` class:

```
private void picbox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: @ Ansis able to create an event but is there any way to id every picbox i created

Answer (score 1):

To get the click event for your dynamically created PictureBox, you can simple subscribe to the click event when you create it;

```
    private void createPicBoxes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
            picBox.Click += picBox_Click;
        }
    }

    static void picBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do your stuff here which handles generically all of your picture boxes clicks.
    }
```

In short, subscribing to the controls events like such means that whenever that action is performed, in your case a click event, the attached method will fire off.

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler to the PictureBox when creating it.
Something like below

```
PictureBox picbox = new PictureBox();
picbox.Click += new EventHandler(this.picbox_Click);
void picbox_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//your code...
}
```

Comment: Oops we have got similar answers earlier by other users. Should have refreshed before posting.